# I accidentally changed default for auto viewing pics in Win 7 [64]

Tags: windows-7

Now  I can't see the pics within a folder.  Any way to reset this to auto show the pic when i click on a folder?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the picture preview function of Explorer it can be toggled on and off by using the "Show/Hide the preview pane" button in Explorer:

[image]